# Errors with pickling objects

Tags: python, pickle

We're making an exercise with pickle, and this code doesn't work as it is supposed to. Please help me, this is the code (some words are in Spanish because I'm from America):

```
import pickle

class persona:

    def __init__(self, nombre, genero, edad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.genero = genero
        self.edad = edad
        print("se ha creado una persona nueva con el nombre de: ", self.nombre)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {} {}".format(self.nombre, self.genero, self.edad)

class listaPersonas:

    personas = []

    def __init__(self):
        listaDePersonas = open("ficheroExterno", "ab+")
        listaDePersonas.seek(0)

        try:
            self.personas = pickle.load(listaDePersonas)
            print("Se cargaron {} personas del fichero externo".format(len(self.personas)))
        except:
            print("El fichero está vacío")

        finally:
            listaDePersonas.close()
            del(listaDePersonas)

    def agregarPersonas(self, p):
        self.personas.append(p)
        self.guardarPersonasEnFicheroExterno()

    def mostrarPersonas(self):
        for p in self.personas:
            print(p)

    def guardarPersonasEnFicheroExterno(self):
        listaDePersonas = open("ficheroExterno", "wb")
        pickle.dump(self.personas, listaDePersonas)
        listaDePersonas.close()
        del(listaDePersonas)

    def mostrarInfoFicheroExterno(self):
        print("La información sle fichero externo es la siguiente: ")
        for p in self.personas:
            print(p)


miLista = listaPersonas()
persona = persona("Sandra", "Femenino", 29)
miLista.agregarPersonas(persona)
miLista.mostrarInfoFicheroExterno()
```

and it throws that:

```
    El fichero está vacío
se ha creado una persona nueva con el nombre de:  Sandra
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Guardado_permanente.py", line 54, in <module>
    miLista.agregarPersonas(persona)
  File "Guardado_permanente.py", line 34, in agregarPersonas
    self.guardarPersonasEnFicheroExterno()
  File "Guardado_permanente.py", line 42, in guardarPersonasEnFicheroExterno
    pickle.dump(self.personas, listaDePersonas)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.persona'>: it's not the same object as __main__.persona

***Repl Closed***
```

I have like 1 1/2 hour that I'm seeing this code and I'm trying to guess which is the problem, but the code is the same as my teacher's code. please, help me. I'm using Sublime text to code.

Comment: Please come up with a better question title; loads of code doesn't work, and it's not really relevant that you are a student. Your question is reasonably decent (it is complete in that it has proper error output, your title is letting you down here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this line, you have replaced your class `persona` with an instance of the class:

```
persona = persona("Sandra", "Femenino", 29)
```

`pickle` is trying to find the class definition for `persona` but can't, because it doesn't have a name anymore.

Don't try to use the same name for two things; only the last assignment counts. [Standard style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is to use CamelCase names for clasess, so you could name your class `Persona` instead.